# How to show .webp in Chrome and .jpg in Firefox or IE/Edge?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

Is there any working example to show `.webp` format file in Chrome and a different `.jpg` format file in Firefox and IE / Edge?

I user now this `CSS` code:

```
#bgbox {
    background-imgage: url('../img/bg.webp');
}
```

Is there a `-moz-background-image` or something like this?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) element and set a `webp` source with a `jpg` fallback. You can have multiple sources and the browser will try to load the first compatible one or use the fallback if none work.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</picture>
```

If you need to set a background however a different approach is needed. You can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to detect if the browser supports `webp` and apply different styles based on that.

```css
.image {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.no-webp .image {
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg');
}

.webp .image {
  background-image: url('http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.webp');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/modernizr/3.3.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use image-set as well like for example:

```
#bgbox {
   background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg');
   background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.webp')1x );
}
```

so browser not supporting `image-set` or `webp` will use the default background-image. so you won't need any javascript like `modernizr`

Comment: This is a neat clean solution but are you sure this won't make the browser download both if it can?  So Chrome gets 2 image downloads?

Comment: No I have tested it.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. But I think there might be some issues due to support of this on Safari ( Refer to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-image-set and https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp)